# How does a function like readFileSync function work in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been reading about how async functions work in Node.js, specially related to the Event Loop, but how does a sync function like readFileSync work?

- Does it participate in the Event Loop at all? if yes in which phase and how runs the corresponding code?
- Is the thread pool used for the corresponding I/O operation as normal? If yes, then how is achieved the sync behaviour since the thread pool operates on it owns in a async way?

Comment: The synchronous functions simply call the underlying native functions directly, blocking the thread until the operation is complete. Why do you think that would (need to) participate in the event loop or thread pool at all?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have no idea how it works, this is because I ask. Is it then the thread pool used for reading the file like in the async readFile function? What does happen when the sync function is executed inside a callback in a specific phase of the Event Loop, does it stop immediately the Event Loop, or wait till the end of the loop?

Comment: As a side note: you can definitely resolve a promise synchronously by waiting for it to resolve, and only return from your function when it resolves / rejects. I don't _think_ that Node does this internally, though; the underlying OSes certainly have much easier ways to achieve synchronous I/O. Resolving other Promises while a sync I/O operation is running is also not very helpful, because the result won't be visible anyway until the sync operation completes.

Comment: The thread pool is used for reading the file asynchronously, yes. It allows the main thread to continue while performing I/O in the background, and posting results to the main thread through the event loop when the operation is complete. If a synchronous I/O is performed in a callback, it will still block the main thread because all callbacks in JavaScript are run in the context of the main thread.

Comment: @9000 you definitely cannot resolve a promise synchronously, because the very operations that need to run in order to signal completion will be blocked by whatever "busy loop" you try to implement. The only way around this is to write native code that modifies how the event loop works like [`deasync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync) for example.